# partition into unit-interval graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, partition-problem, interval-graphs

I am re-opening [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20843/partition-into-interval-graphs) question as i have the following question.
I was going through the [paper by Farrugia](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v11i1r46/pdf) which was mentioned in an answer in that post. Initially i beleived that the follwoing problem is NP-Complete.

Suppose there is a graph $G=(V,E)$. I want to test if V can be partitioned into two disjoint sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that the subgraphs induced by $V_1$ and $V_2$ are unit interval graphs.

But in the paper,there is a theorem which says

> Let $A$ and $B$ be additive induced-hereditary properties. Then there
>   is a polynomial-time transformation from the $A$-recognition problem
>   to the $(A◦B)$-recognition problem.

So, my question is that :- is it possible that because of the above theorem the problem might be solvable in polynomial time ??

Comment: what is an 'additive' property ?

Comment: That paper's main theorem shows that your problem is NP hard, as I think unit interval graphs satisfy the conditions of the hardness proof. The theorem you cite does not help in recognizing (A◦B) graphs... many easy problems can polynomially reduce to a hard problem. E.g. Every problem in P polynomially reduces to an NP-complete problem.